# Android How can I make a Linear layout scrollable programmatically?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I have a menu in my android application, I want to make my linear layout scrollable on menu item's click. I don't want to do this using xml.
Please, how can I do this ?
Note: I am using c# in my code.

Comment: you need to first add ScrollView to rootView and then LinearLayout to ScrollView.

Comment: Why not just use a list view?

Comment: Cannot use listview. I have textview and imagebutton in my layout.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(context);
scroll.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
scroll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
scroll.addView(yourTableView);
```

Comment: First, those code are java so I translated them to c# and tried them. I got the exception The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.